# MathJax tutorial for linear programming missing in search results

Tags: discussion, bug, mathjax, search, meta

## Background

An [answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27756/290189) for typing [linear-programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-programming) questions in [mathjax](/questions/tagged/mathjax) has been added to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) since one year.

## Problem

I attempted to find it by [search](/questions/tagged/search) on this [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) site with keyword "linear programming".  Unluckily, [the search results](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=linear+programming) *didn't* show the [desired MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27756/290189).

**Why is the tutorial hidden from the search result?  How can this community wiki (CW) post be improved so that it's searcheable with "linear programming"?**

## Why this is relevant

### Importance of using MathJax for mathematical discourse

- [Why use MathJax? It's so slow](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/743/why-use-mathjax-its-so-slow)
- [What is the incentive to use MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19116/what-is-the-incentive-to-use-mathjax)
- [Should MathJaX be pointed out to new users?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17134/should-mathjax-be-pointed-out-to-new-users)

Exception: It's reported that MathJax's support for commutative diagrams is *primitive* and AMScd's syntax differs greatly from that of the usual $\rm\LaTeX$ packages that mathematicians usually use.  I am *not* using them, so I *can't* judge on that.

### Benefits of pictures in [learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning)

Scientific researches has shown that [human mind perceives images much faster than text](https://www.psychologytoday.com/intl/blog/get-psyched/201207/learning-through-visuals).  Therefore, [A picture is worth a thousand words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122091/259305).

### Situation in [linear-programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-programming)

Despite the possibility of typing [tables in MathJax](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4240/290189), many users are still posting images like this.

[image: sample simplex tableau]
Source: [simplex algorithm with tableau](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1149195/290189)

It's quite tedious/difficult to reconstruct a simplex from text in some questions like [Minimisation using Simplex Tableau](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1995969/290189).  Due to the amount of effort needed, such questions are less likely to be answered.

IMHO, a nice MathJax template for simplex tableau has the following benefits when compared to images.

\begin{array}{rrrrrr|r}
               & x_1 & x_2 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 &    \\ \hline
           s_1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &  8 \\
           s_2 &   1 &  -1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &  4 \\
           s_3 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 & 12 \\ \hline
               &  -1 &  -1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &  0
\end{array}

- takes up less size (both file size and visual size)
- better resolution
- easier to reproduce and manipulate (with a text editor like [Vim](https://www.vim.org), [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), etc)

### Negative impact of pic questions to the site's SEO

[Avoid using pictures as essential part of post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) is *not* simply a [SE network's policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155601/259305), but a way to be nice with others, especially to those who use screen readers and to search bots who *can't* interpret images, such as [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/spread)'s search bot and [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz).<sup>1</sup>  Having pic questions is bad for the site in terms of [search engine optimisation](https://varvy.com/textversusimages.html) (SEO) since there's *no* relevant keyword for the search bot to grab in a pic question.

### Conclusion

- Images convey messages much faster than text.

  - They can be used for illustration purposes.
  - They are not shortcut to typing math/text.
  - Use SE's image uploader instead of external image hosts.
- Text is much better than images in terms of SEO
- Use MathJax if possible
- MathJax tutorial for [linear-programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-programming) provides templates for LPPs and simplex tableaux.
- Be nice to each other, including those who can and cannot view images

---

<sup>1</sup> With an exception to [geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry), [visualization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualization) like questions due to the subject nature.

Comment: I was able to [find your addition to the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmathjax%5D+simplex) using search terms `[mathjax]` and `simplex`.  Note that the tag [meta-tag:mathjax] rather than the simple search term `mathjax` is helpful here because the tags are pulled from the framing Question (and need not be repeated in the post itself).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is the tutorial hidden from the search result? How can this community wiki (CW) post be improved so that it's searcheable with "linear programming"?

The post did not contain the key-word. It seems to appear only once, and at that place there was a typo, it said "programminng."

Having corrected the typo it now does show up. To include the keyword more than once might show it up earlier in the list by relevance (not sure about this though).

Beyond that, first, thanks for having written the answer. Second, there might be a broader issue lurking, in that the tutorial thread by now has gotten quite broad. On some devices getting to display that thread is by now a challenge. It might be a good idea to present some of the  information differently, via separate questions for example.  But that discussion is beyond the scope of this post.