# Why people vote negative when you clearly show the question and your working

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I have a question about my Mathematics Stack Exchange post: [Van Dyke's matching principles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3640137/van-dykes-matching-principles)

Comment: You write that you have a question about your post, but I don't see any question. Oh, I see a question in the title, but the way we do things here, the question is supposed to be *in the body of the post*, not (just) in the title. Please edit to comply.

Comment: I see you've deleted your post on main. Pity. I hope you're taking the opportunity to edit it in accord with the advice you have received here, and that you'll undelete it when you get it up to the wbesite's standards.

Comment: No Gery, I checked it with my Doctor at the university he was able to help, people voted negative because they didn't understand it, thanks for your effort, best wishes.

Comment: How do you contact here someone directly? message pm ... etc

Comment: There is, in general, no way to contact someone directly here, Simon. But if you want to make sure that I see your reply to a comment of mine, you just put @Gerry into your comment. Anyway, I'm glad to hear that a doctor was able to help you with a math problem, most of the doctors I know are useless at mathematics. And I'm sorry that you still have no clue as to why users downvote questions here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think OP means a PhD, not a MD.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I haven't downvoted you, but I would expect it's because you've provided links to images rather than writing the mathematics out.

The site expects questions to be self-contained, and having to click a link to see your question, then two(!) more links to see your answer is (though it may not seem like it to you) quite a lot of work.  At a minimum, someone trying to answer has to have four tabs open -- one for each of your links, plus math.stackexchange -- and has to keep switching between them.

Next but related: by putting everything in a link it becomes very hard to refer to anywhere in your text to point out a mistake or even where you've done something well.  You may also find it hard to follow an answer that has to keep saying "line 6 of the second answer link...".  If you type it all out, someone can cut'n'paste the relevant section from your question into their answer to explain it.

Lastly: you picked the wrong tag really, though that's not that surprising since you're new here.  You want the proof-verification tag since that's what you're asking for.  The calculus tag attracts a lot of attention, but (and I may be being a little unfair here, this is entirely my opinion and should be treated as such) it also attracts a lot of people who want to read and quickly answer a question.  You may get downvotes because they are annoyed that instead of a question you've posted three links.

I don't think the core of your question is bad at all -- but your presentation isn't helping you, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I added photos because it's difficult to type it here especially with a lot of maths formulas ao I found that it's easier to type it on the word document and then attach a photo for it here, this is my answer and I worked few days on it I feel that it's unfair, I feel that people just voted negative because they didn't know how to answer it which is unfair . , thank you for your reply

Comment: Let y = e^rx                          y’=r e^rx                     y ‘’= r^2 e^rx
Substitute into (2) 
ɛ r^2 e^rx + 2r e^rx-e^rx= 0 
÷ e^rx
       ɛ r^2  + 2r -1 = 0 If I just type it here this is how it will look like

Comment: To your second comment: use MathJax to format your maths (see here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference ).  This is strongly related to Latex and will be useful for all your maths in life :)  For feeling things are unfair -- you won't like my answer but: lots of things in life are unfair.  You manage them best by understanding what you can change and what you can't.  What you can change here is how the question is presented.  Complaining that other people should change has a much lower chance of success I'm afraid.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30186) are some additional reasons the community prefers properly typed questions. In brief: better searching, improved accessibility, and better SEO.

Comment: What it comes down to, Simon, is: do you want an answer to your question, or don't you? If you do, then it stands to reason that you should do everything you can to make it *easy* for people to answer your question, and that includes writing it out instead of making people chase it, and it includes learning something about how to format mathematics on these websites. If you don't really care whether or not anyone answers your question, then you're doing just fine – keep up the good work!

Comment: @postmortes  You've been writing some really good answers on meta!  Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Thanks for the effort, all sorted now, best wishes everyone and thanks for the advice.